# How to protect a class member?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I have a class *myclass* that encapsulate an fstream-pointer (not simply fstream because of the fact that fstream have a private assignment operator declared, so I can't correctly copy an instance of *myclass*, but that's not the problem!).

Also, my class has two functions, *open()* and *close()* which opens and closes the fstream object respectively. The fact that the fstream is open, is recorded into a private variable *bool isOpen* inside myclass.

So, if any other function implemented into the instance of *myclass* can be executed only if *isOpen == true*.

I would like that, when I copy an instance of *myclass*, the fstream-pointer point to null and/or *isOpen == false* in every case. In this way, I don't allow different instances to use the same file. In a certain way, I'm protecting the value that another instance has.

So, how can I define the assignment operator of *myclass? Or maybe, there is some other way?

Comment: Uh … if you don’t want to allow different classes to access the same file you don’t need to have a pointer to `fstream`, you can have an `fstream` directly in the class, and simply not copy it on assignment.

Comment: ggod point, but I would like to know how to deal with this situation in general, even when I don't have a file, but some other thing I want to protect.

Comment: @the_candyman: the usual thing is to _not have a copy assignment operator_ since you can't copy the stream.  It's highly recommended to use a move assignment operator instead.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks for the reply. But I don't really know what a move assignment operator is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph After a good sleep, I realized that you are suggesting to write an assignment operator in which all internal variables are copied except for the fstream. Definitely, such approach is general, I think. That's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement a copy constructor AND an assignment operator for your class.

Also (if you still use a pointer member to the fstream object despite "Konrad Rudolf" suggested not to do so) do not forget to `delete` the pointer in your destructor to have the destructor of the `fstream` object called that closes the opened file. You cannot be sure that each `open()` will have a `close()` pair.

Comment: You needn’t bother closing file handles explicitly; the `fstream` destructor does so for you.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Good point, I updated the answer. My intention was that the code should not rely on that `close()` will be called.

Comment: @Csq As said before to KonradRudolph, you are suggesting to write an assignment operator in which all internal variables are copied except for the fstream. That's right? Same arguments for the copy constructor?

Comment: Yes. Be sure to write both the copy ctr and the assignment operator. If you don't know how to do it, Google is your friend.